# problems with pointers in C , can't find my mistakes

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have worked on this 2 days now and can't find my mistakes, the program runs but it stops ( waiting ) after I enter 3 or 4. can anyone help me where are my mistakes please?

The program should do the following :

User will be asked how many numbers he wants to enter ( 3 or 4 ).
3 or 4 integer values will be entered from user and saved inside an array.
The program counts how many zeros the user entered.
The program then doubles the array to the double size, where each element has a copy of itself next to it.
Print out the new array at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int cnt = 0;


/* Read <cnt> Integers into given array.
Return number of entered zeros */
int* readInts(int *arr) {
    int i=0, *zeros = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    while(i <= cnt) {
        scanf("%d", arr++);
        if (arr[i++] == 0) *zeros++;
    }
    return zeros;
}

/* Create "double-sized" copy of array (duplicate each value)*/
void extend(int *arr, int *newarr) {
    int i,j;
    newarr = (int*) malloc(2 * cnt * sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0,j=0; i <= cnt; i++) {
        newarr[j++] = arr[i];
        newarr[j++] = arr[i];
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[4], *zeros, i;
    printf("How many integers (3 or 4)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &cnt);

    zeros = readInts(arr); 
    printf("You entered %d zero(s)!\n", *zeros);

    int *newarr;
    extend(arr, newarr);

    for (i=0; i < cnt*2; i++) printf("%d ", newarr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than asking for the answers, this might be a useful read for you: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

That is because you use `while(i <= cnt)` when it should be `while(i < cnt)` (twice).

But after that, you'll get a segmentation fault.
You pass `newarr` to `extend` before assigning it a value.
Inside `extend` you assign it a value, but that doesn't change outside the function, so you'll (most likely) hit a segmentation fault on `printf("%d ", newarr[i]);`
Also you should replace `int*` by `int` in `malloc(2 * cnt * sizeof(int*));`.
But to avoid the segmentation fault, you have two easy options (ofc there are a lot more complicated ones):

1. Initialise `newarr` before passing it to `extend`:
   `int *newarr = (int*) malloc(2 * cnt * sizeof(int));`
2. Change `void extend(int *arr, int *newarr)`
   to `int* extend(int *arr)` and just `return newarr;` at the end of `extend`.